# Estimate the risk for upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, upgrade

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 Education on dual boot. I'd like to upgrade to 18.04 but after researching on this topic I see that it quite often comes to severe problems. So I would like to ask if I can make a kind of diagnostics for my system(s) to find out if there could be any problems?

That is my system:

**~$ lsb_release -a**

```
  No LSB modules are available. 
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS Release: 16.04 Codename: xenial
```

**df -Th | grep -v fs**

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb5      ext4       14G  9,1G  3,5G  73% /
/dev/sda1      vfat      1,9T  616G  1,3T  34% /media/alexey511/INTENSO
```

Win10 and Ubuntu are on the same SSD. I use ProBook 440 G4. 
NB: Currently struggling with the problem: "unable to resolve host".

Comment: Can you elaborate about your system still more? Have you installed Windows-10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on separate SSDs? Or you installed them on a single hard disk with separate partitions? Is it a desktop?

Comment: I hope you have a working windows-10 installation already present on your laptop. So please don't bother about windows-10 now (you take care of license issues separately). At present, you want to know the risks involved in upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04. Unless you have any appllications that soley depend upon 16.04, there are no risks. If you have any data or source code stored in 16.04, please take a back-up.  Please go ahead and upgrade! Even you can  edit/alter your partition tables during Ubuntu 18.04 installation using option `something else`. You will be good!

Comment: You alse expressed some problems with `creating a new installation disc for windows-10`. When you purchased `ProBook 440 G4` laptop, didn't you receive any installable CDs from vendor(HP)? What was your windows-10 edition (home or professional)? Do you have any product-key?

Comment: You have `unable to resolve host` problem. Please edit your question and post output of the following commands: 1. `cat /etc/hostname` and 2. `cat /etc/hosts`

Comment: Hi @Marmayogi I solved the `resolve host` problem. However, here is the output of `cat /etc/hostname`: **rgb-3345** and `cat /etc/hosts`: **127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 rgb-3345**

Comment: _Windows 10 Education_ is already present on my laptop. If I'll need to reinstall it I should buy another version as I am not a student anymore. I'd rather keep the Education version as long as it works.

Comment: Have you upgraded your Ubuntu, @alex511ZU? My suggestion is you  may upgrade to 19.04 instead of 18.04.

Comment: Not yet. Is it Ok to upgrade directly from 16 to 19?

Comment: You can't directly upgrade from 16 to 19. You upgrade first to 18.04, and then to 18.10 and finally 19.10. i.e. the transition is  16.04 -> 18.04 -> 18.10 -> 19.10. Instead, why don't you make a clean install of 19.04 directly from16.04? Do you have a lot of data to back up in your 16.04 system?

Comment: There are almost no data. Originally I installed 16.04 just to try it out. Also, I would like to expand the Linux partition. Do you have a link on how to make _a clean install of 19.04_?

Comment: There is a [visual youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpBO3EKKd8U) which is useful to begin with. You may refer this [tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/ubuntu-19-04-installation-on-uefi-firmware/) for step-by-step installation instructions for Ubuntu 19.04. Good luck @alex511ZU!

Comment: Should I delete 16.04 before?

Comment: No need. A clean installation simply overwrites on existing 16.04 ubuntu. You directly download ISO image (19.04 Disco Dingo) from [official website](http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.04/) and choose 64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image.  Please read my answer to the post [What does it mean to make a bootable LiveUSB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125710/what-does-it-mean-to-make-a-bootable-liveusb/1125721#1125721) where you will find **step-by-step instructions to prepare bootable USB stick** using Rufus from ISO image. If you need more help regarding installation, please contact me again!