# Installation problems with 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: boot, 18.04, system-installation, oem

If the OEM install is used, the install to disk and boot from HDD works properly. Normal install fails to boot from HDD after install. What is the difference between these two install options?

Comment: Is it desktop or laptop? You used a phrase **install to disk**. What is disk? Is it SSD? Do you have SSD and HDD in your system? What is the difference between OEM install and normal install? Is it a dual boot system? Please clarify.

Comment: It is a desktop installation onto a 6TB Seagate HDD, no other disk drives, other than a DVD drive. The desktop is a i9 7960x with 128GB of RAM on an Asus X299 Mark 1. I even took the HDD from another 16.04 desktop and booted the machine from that install, but when I go back to a fresh install on the 6TB HDD, it does not boot from HDD after install. OEM install does boot from HDD(6TB). Why the difference?

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu 18.04 on HDD? is it through DVD or a bootable USB stick?  After install, did you access BIOS setup screen by pressing `del` key? Did you observe  any bootloaders there? After installation, could you logon to Ubuntu at least once? Did you try the  command `sudo update-grub` to create GRUB menu? Please clarify.

Comment: It is a new 6TB HDD with nothing on it. It is a fresh verified copy of Ubuntu 18.04.2 on a DVD drive. The del key went to bios where DVD was put in first place for boot up. Install menu comes up, install process is done, but when restart, the system does not boot from HDD, not even once. I have no desire to have this machine dual boot, just Ubuntu 18.04.2 only, no other bootloaders.

Comment: I need partition details, @spoatech. What kind of  partition plan did you implement on 6TB HDD during Ubuntu installation, such as `efi`, `"\"`, `swap`, `tmp`, `home`, and so on. Can you explain, please.

Comment: I've tried several different ones like /bios, /boot, /, /swap and /bios, /boot, /swap, / and /bios, /efi, /swap, / and even one partition "/". They all wind up in the same place. The system boot from DVD into Live, goes through the install process and none boot from HDD afterwards.

Comment: I've also removed all partitions and let Ubuntu install create them ... nothing works. It installs, but won't boot from HDD after install.

Comment: Is your bootable  DVD `UEFI` enabled? i.e., Ubuntu should be installed with `efi` boot loader. BTW, do you have access to any spare laptop (with windows installation) with a USB port and DVD drive? If so, let us prepare a bootable USB stick using Rufus tool. Rufus will use the ISO image of Ubuntu from DVD and prepare USB stick. You have to set two parameters properly in Rufus while preparing bootable USB stick: 1. Partition scheme” to `“GPT"` and  2. “Target system” as `“UEFI (non CSM)`.

Comment: Yes, I have two working 16.04 Linux machines, 2 working Windows 7 machines and a Windows 10 laptop. So, take your pick from these platforms to make this work. The UEFI information is something I needed to know about as these are choices in the BIOS that I need to set. The How To tutorials don't make these clear, whether to use or not.

Comment: Please ignore your `DVD` and you directly download `ISO` image from [official website](http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/) and choose `64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop` image.
Using the downloaded ISO, prepare a bootable USB (at least 4 GB capacity) stick through [Rufus 3.5](https://rufus.ie/). Please read my answer to the post [What does it mean to make a bootable LiveUSB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125710/what-does-it-mean-to-make-a-bootable-liveusb/1125721#1125721) where you will find **step-by-step instructions to prepare USB stick** for `Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver` using Rufus.

Comment: Please go ahead and install ubuntu 18.04 using `bootall USB stick` on your desktop with `motherboard Asus X299 Mark 1`. Please refer my answer to the post [Dual Boot Windows 10 and Linux Ubuntu on Separate SSD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033497/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-ssd/1126970#1126970). Even though the above link deals with subject `dual-boot`, @spoatech, you just refer only **Part-II** and **Part-III** of my answer, and you will be good! If you have any questions, please let me know! Good luck!

Comment: @Marmayogi - Created the USB stick and it installed the same way that the DVD did ... no difference. After installation, the system boots from HDD, Ubuntu screen comes up and then screen goes blank and stays in this state indefinitely. What now?

Comment: Did you reach the GUI login screen? Did you attempt to login? Please be specific at what point your screen went to blank? Can you access internet?

Comment: The Ubuntu logo comes up with the dots and sits in this state what seems to be a normal length of time. Then the screen goes blank and stays in this state indefinitely. I have been researching video driver issues with Nouveau drivers as a possible cause for this, but not sure if this is the cause.

Comment: I can take a working 16.04 HDD from another workstation and put that drive into this computer and it will boot normally all the way through to the desktop, so I am confident that the machine hardware is OK. The machine will boot from both Live DVD and Live UEFI USB stick all the way through to the desktop. I can see the HDD and can even read and write files to it, but the boot process from the HDD ends after the Ubuntu logo with dots ends ... the screen goes blank and the machine becomes unresponsive.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92926/discussion-on-question-by-spoatech-installation-problems-with-18-04-2-lts).

Answer (score 0):

Gave up on 18.04LTS. Downloaded Ubuntu Studio 19.04, burned to DVD, installed from DVD and booted from hard disk first try ... 18.04LTS install scripts have bugs!